# Network-related or instance-specific error when running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I have Problem when I run my web project

Error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)**

Then I found in SQL Server Configuration Manager that SQL Server Express stopped

When I'm trying to run SQL Server Express, an error appears

Error :

> the request failed or the service did not respond in timely fashion.
>   Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details

When I open services.msc to start SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS` instance) then this error happen

Error:

> Window could not start the sql server (SQLEXPRESS) on local Computer.
>   For more information , review the System Evemt Log. If this is a non
>   -Microsoft service,contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 3417

Any solution to solve my problem ???

Comment: This question should be on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also, did you search first? At all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express And did you review the event log, like the error message suggested?