# How i can connect PHP to SQL Server with IP Address

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2, ip

I cant connect to the database with my PC IP Adress, but i can connect to the database with my PC Name. How i can fix it or i can configure it in sql server ?

So, what are the differences between PC Name and 127.0.0.1 to connect SQL Server ?

Here is different my code:

```
mssql_connect("MYPCNAME","sa","solution") or die('Connection Failed'); //this is OK

mssql_connect("127.0.0.1","sa","solution") or die('Connection Failed'); // this is failed
```

i need your expertise ;)

Comment: WHat happens, what error messages do you get? Is `MYPCNAME` actually your local computer?

Comment: Is apache and mysql servers turned on? Are you using xampp?

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov: Please read the question, the OP is using MSSQL, not MySQL. And Apache is completely unrelated to this issue.

Comment: Check your DNS configuration. Sounds like there will be a `resolv` error somewhere.

Comment: How exactly is DNS involved when using `127.0.0.1` For that IP even the reverse lookup usually does not use a DNS server.

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express

Comment: @Pekka : Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 127.0.0.1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\risets\mssql_conn.php on line 3 , and if i change the 127.0.0.1 with MYPCNAME( my computer name ) it can successfully connected.

Comment: @Nurland : my Apache was turned on, i don't need mysql so i turn it off...

@ Whisperity : how i can find the configuration option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may work if you are using the port number, e.g.:

```
mssql_connect("127.0.0.1:1433","sa","solution") or die('Connection Failed');
```

If you are using PHP on Windows try:

```
 mssql_connect("127.0.0.1,1433","sa","solution") or die('Connection Failed');
```

Comment: i was try that and coonfigure in windows firewall to open the port, but still can't connect.. :(

Comment: you can try mssql_connect("127.0.0.1:1433\\database","sa","solution") or die('Connection Failed'); or see my above answer(edited)

Comment: i still can't connect to other PC... is there have an configuration on the other PC that i want to connect ?

Answer (score 0):

When using a hostname it usually resolves to the non-loopback address of the machine. Using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` will always use the loopback interface.

Most likely SQL Server does not bind to the loopback interface but only to the real interface (the one with the IP you get when resolving `MYPCNAME`). You could either keep using a PC Name or its IP or configure SQL Server to listen on the loopback interface, too.