# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio - Connect/Server/Instance Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

firstly i recently installed this program as I’m working on a project to create a database to use in Microsoft visual studio.

This is the first time I’m using the program, so I’m having a few problems setting it up. I can't connect to a server because presumably i don't have one. I typed in my machine name to create a default/localhost server using windows authentication but i received an error.

Error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Could someone guide me on how i can setup up a local host to connect and thus be able to create my database. Also I’d like to know afterwards how i can create a server (ftp) to connect into and create my database there allowing me to view this on my laptop or a different machine.

Btw i have looked on Google for this, but I’m getting a bit confused, because I’m unsure what I’m searching for. If anyone can shed some light on my problem i would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express?rq=1

Comment: Check "Named Pipes" is enabled for this instance (from SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Comment: MachineName\SQLEXPRESS worked for me thnx.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Does Your server name looks like : "localhost ( or IP of Your server
   )"\"server name", E.G : localhost\SQLEXPRESS
2. Open application on Start ->  -> Configuration Tools -> SQL    Server Configuration Manager
3. Check, if MSSQL Server Service was started in :Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services. If not, right click on service and choose Start
4. Check on Configuration Manager on "SQL Server Network Configuration" does "TCP\IP" protocol is enabled and has "Listen All" enabled
5. Check, do You have firewall on port 1433

If that doesn't help, write a message

Comment: Hi thnx, i changed it to MachineName\SQLEXPRESS and it worked

Comment: i also changed it to MachineName\SQLEXPRESS and it worked. Thank uh

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and I have solve this problem by doing following 2 step:

### **1st Task:**

Open application on Start -> -> Configuration Tools -> **SQL Server Configuration Manager**
Check, if MSSQL Server Service was started in :**Sql Server Configuration Manager** -> SQL Server Services. If not, right click on service and choose Start
Check on Configuration Manager on "SQL Server Network Configuration" does "TCP\IP" protocol is enabled and has "Listen All" enabled

**2nd Task:** 
Provide Server Name : [hostname]\SQLEXPRESS 
Authentication : SQL Server Authentication  or Windows authentication
**Note: 
If Server you have installed with Mixex mode then only it will work for SA (SQL Server Authentication) or else we need to used Windows authentication**

Now you should be able to connect if you follow this 2 task.

Answer (score 1):

-> Go To SQL Server Configuration Manager
-> Click to SQL Server Services
-> Right click to SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) and click start, then see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

One the main SQL Server Studio screen, enter for Server name:

> \.\pipe\MSSQL$"your instancename"\sql\query

Answer (score 0):

After a number of trials of restarting services in configuration manager, allowing port 1433 in firewall, restarting computer etc. nothing was working, at last I tried .\SQLEXPRESS ('.' represents localhost) rather than MYMACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS and it worked straight away. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Open Startup Menu and type 'SQL Server Configuration Manager'. After staring the utility select 'SQL Server Services'. Run 'SQL Server' service, that's all.

Right-click on 'SQL Server' service and select properties. Under service pane, set the 'Startup Mode' to automatic, so it will automatically start in future.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but i tried to resolve it .
Please follow these steps to connect to your SQL server Management studios
Run->services.msc->search for SQL Server(MSSQLServer)->Right click on it and try to "start" running it.
By doing this you can surely solve connection issue of SQL server.

Alekya

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, So I **enabled Named pipes** protocol and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Hi every one.
             I find out the solution.
 To establish connection follow these stips.
1.Click on Start >> Sql Server Management Studio.
        Management studio windows will open .and will ask to connect to the sever name etc.  Just cancel it the connect window.

2. Now you go to the left panel of your Object explorer which is Registered servers.
   Click on Database engine.

3.It has normally a folder Local server group. Open it by clicking the plus sign.
  which will show you your server name with cross sign ON.

4.Right click on it and then click on service control. and then click Start.
Now it will start your database engine.

5.Now double click on you engine and it will work as normal.