# What server name to use for MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new at SQL Servers. Don't know how to connect to server. Can anyone tell me how can I create new server for developing C# desktop application with database.

[image: 2]

Comment: Server name: (localdb)\v11.0

Comment: what version ur sql server is & is it express?

Comment: @CircleHsiao its 2012, not express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A network-related or instance-specific error occurred](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/49365/5203)

Comment: r u sure it is operating? u can check this by Sql Server Configuration Manager

Comment: @CircleHsiao IT IS NOT SHOWING ANY ITEMS WHEN I CLICK THERE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11629475/5396995

Answer (score 0):

For your local instance use:

```
 .
```

and choose Windows Authentication so you don't have to enter SQL credentials.

Comment: open SQL Server Manager and enable Named Pipes (should have been enabled by default)

Answer (score 0):

There is one easy way to Browse servers in your system

open your Connect to server Dialog box, in server name drop down you will find Browse for more option at last. [image: See This image]

Now, You will have two tabs, Local server and Network server.

In Local server, you can see your available MS SQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best place to start.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

For your specific scenario, you want this.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

From there, you have several options.

```
Standard Security
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

OR

```
Trusted Connection
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

etc...