# SQLException was unhandled A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010 in my win7 32 bit. They were installed correctly. And each works well alone. But when I want to connect to SQL Server Management Studio from visual Studio I get this error. (I want to connect to a local data base):

> SQLException was unhandled A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote
>   connections.(provider:Named Pipes Provider,error:40-could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

This is my code for connection:

```
cn = new SqlConnection();
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=XXX_amlak; User ID=sa; password=XXX";
cn.Open();
```

Comment: Which version of SQL server you have installed. Express or Standard??

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Use this connectionstring to connect to local database:

`cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SqlExpress; Initial Catalog=XXX_amlak; User ID=sa; password=XXX";`

OR check out this question:
[How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)