# cannot connect to pc-name\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms-2005

While trying to connect to SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition through SQL Server Management Studio 2005 I get the following error:

[image: screen shoot of error is given bellow]

I put all my effort to solve this problem but there is no solution. On stack overflow in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express#3461900) I found this screen shot:
[image: solution of screen shot]

When I see my connect to server dialog box I find the difference like

[image: my connect to server dialog box]

What is the problem?

This SQL server runs on a single machine, not on a cluster or on a client server.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your `local` or `localhost` or `.` as server name ?

Comment: Are you sure that your `SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)` service is running?

Comment: yes i am sure thses ae runing

Comment: yes try using . but nothing same error

Comment: you are not ablke to connect via windows as well as sa user?
Check your sqlbrowser service is runing.
Also check whether namedpipe and TCPIPr both are checked in surface area configuration

Comment: yes i have done you tell @KamranShahid butt same error can you help me by cumming on team viewer. or any one

Answer (score 52):

[image]

Go to services (services.msc) and restart the services in the image and then try to connect.

Comment: trying this but fail then restart machine but fail and even uninssall and then install again fail seeing this error 26 error

Answer (score 36):

If you have ***Microsoft Windows 10***:

1. Type ***Control Panel*** on *Cortana* search bar (which is says by default '**Type here to search**').
   Or click on Windows icon and type **Control Panel**
2. Click on **Administrative Tools**
3. Then double click on **Services**
4. Scroll down and look for: **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)**, after that *right click*
5. And then in the pop out windows click on **Start**

Now you should be able to connect to your ***pc-name\SQLEXPRESS***

Comment: Run the Computer Management applet from Control Panel→Administrative Tools→Computer Management, where you should find the configuration manager installed.

Answer (score 7):

When you get this error.

Follow these steps then you solve your problem

1. Open command prompt by pressing (window + r) keys or Click on windows Button and Type Run then type **services.msc** and click OK or press Enter key.

2.Find **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)**.

3.Now see left upper side and click start.

4.If Service show error then right click on SQL Express and then click on Properties.

5.Then click on Logon Tab.

6.Enter Username and Password of Windows Authentication

7.Then Start your Service

8.Problem will be solve and run your query

Answer (score 6):

Use (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB as the server name

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps then you solve your problem 100%.

1. When you get this error then close everything(Microsoft SQL Server Managment):

[image: error]

2. Then open command prompt by pressing (`window` + `r`) keys and type `services.msc` and click OK or press Enter key.
3. And search **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) as I show in the image.

[image]

4. Now see left upper side and click start.
5. If you open Microsoft SQL Server Management then you not get any type error.

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm Running Windows 10 and this worked for me:

1. Open services by searching in the toolbar for Services.
2. Right click SQL Server (SQLEXPESS)
3. Go To Properties - Log On
4. Check Local System Account & Allow service to interact with desktop.
5. Apply and restart service.
6. I was then able to connect

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the SQL Server Browser Service.

Answer (score 1):

try using IP instead of pc name. If the ip working, then it might be the name pipe is not enable. If it;s still not working then the login using windows might be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.
So I put like this:
PC-NAME\SQLSERVER
Since the SQLSERVER the instance name that was set at installation.

Authentication: Windows Authentication

Connects !!!

Answer (score 1):

My issue occurs when I add a PC to a domain.  Restarting the service, making sure it's running, that it has the correct credentials to run, etc, as in other answers doesn't work.  I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I can't even log in with the local user anymore to give the domain user access.  Here's the steps that work for me:

In **SSMS**

- View > Registered Servers
- Database Engine > Local Server Groups > right-click `pcname\sqlexpress`
- Delete > Yes
- Right-click Local Server Groups > Tasks > Register Local Servers
- It confirms that it re-registered.  `pcname\sqlexpress` reappears.

I'm then able to log in with the local windows auth'd user again, my databases are all there and everything.  I then go about my business adding the domain user to Security > Logins.

Answer (score 0):

go to services and start the ones related to SQL

Comment: Please provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was copying and pasting the server name from `appsettings.json` as;

`DESKTOP-IVQP9DJ\\SQLEXPRESS`.

So the problem was that there were two slashes in the server name which was causing the issue for me.
If you are using `.net core` and copying/pasting server name like me make sure to use only one slash as:

`DESKTOP-IVQP9DJ\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 0):

If you already did [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15)
Then just restart the service :

1. start menu
2. Microsoft SQL Server 20xx
3. Sql Server 20xx Configuration Manager
4. SQL Server Service (at left tree)
5. SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) (at right region)
6. right click -> restart