# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 no database engines

Tags: sql-server-2012

I just installed MS SQL Server 2012 (Express). I went through the whole install process from SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe (other things were already installed) with checking all the checkboxes, so I thought I had everything necessary.

When I try to connect to .\sqlexpress, I get a message saying "Cannot connect to .\sqlexpress". See below for message detail, I copied it from another question because mine is in Dutch :-)
[Cannot connect to .\sqlexpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332418/cannot-connect-to-pc-name-sqlexpress)

I did some research through my friends Google and Stackoverflow, but none of the solutions work.
1. There is nothing in Database Engine -> Local Server Groups -> Register Local Servers (it says "No local servers of type "Database Engine" were found"
2. I cannot restart the services as I only have one "SQL related" service (SQL Server VSS Writer)
3. There are no services listed in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services

Does anybody know what's wrong? Please let me know if you need additional details.
Thanks, a SQL Server newbie

Comment: I have no idea why you have been voted down. Your post helped me

Comment: Somebody please address my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/q/38916894/6709147

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The *SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe* as the name says only contains **SQL Server Management Studio**, which is the GUI used to manage servers. It does NOT includes any DB engine or anything else but the client tool, so it's normal that you don't have the service installed.

Look at the downloads at the [official download website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29062). The file named *SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe* or *SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe* are the full installs that includes both the client tools and database engine together. It's normally the best possible download I can think of from all the choices.

Comment: I installed this about 6 months ago, but there must have been something wrong, because now I deinstalled everything, installed it again and now it works like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correct the file `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` only contains the management tools and not the server software. You need to download another file (`SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` if you want the complete package with server and reporting services etc.).

[See this page for more information](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have completed whole installation process without any error.

It may possible that you have installed it with another instance name and possibly because of that you are getting this message.

Following thing you have to check.

1. Try to access on Same machine where you have installed SQL Server using Management studio.
2. Start menu or Search for SQL Server Configuration tool. At that tool you will find SQL server instance. name.
3. Make sure that your instance is running mode.
4. Which authentication mode you have choose during installation and take proper step during making connection

If above step will not work then please provide more detail.

Comment: I had no instances there so I could not solve it this way. Anyway I reinstalled everything and now it works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You need to Download the SQL Server Express Edition with the **Advanced Services** option.

```
ADV - with advanced services (reporting services)
```