# Error when install sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server, installation

I install Sql server 2008 on Window server 2008( x64) then get one error( bellow screenshot) :
        http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/30/wic3.png/

```
    I don't know why. Can you help me to fix this error! Thanks. I have turned of firewall.
```

Comment: You can often find a solution quickly, by TYPING YOUR ERROR MESSAGE into a search box. You've probably gotten no responses because you gave a screen shot instead. Putting it in quotes can help, esp. on google.  Doing that for you led to these links **[on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0628296e-939a-4700-b498-1c3c9ce90597/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlsecurity)**, and **[here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)**.