# Can Telerik Reporting Connect to SQL LocalDb for Development?

Tags: localdb, telerik-reporting

We are developing an ASP.Net/Angular Single Page Application and are considering using Telerik Reporting. During development we use a SQL LocalDb database. Does anyone know if Telerik Reporting can connect to SQL LocalDb please?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, yes, but getting ASP.NET to connect to LocalDb is hard, consider using SQL Server Express instead.

Comment: That's interesting. My Web API connects with no problem so I guess I can use the same connection string?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
So I was actually able to get this to work by following the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852205/16501.

Steps:

1. Share the localdb instance by running "sqllocaldb MSSQLLocalDB .\shareddb"
2. Setup a login in your sql server instance
3. Your connection string should look something like this: "Data Source=(LocalDb).\shareddb;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test"

Things to note:

1. The database has to be started for you to connect.  When connecting with named pipes this happens automatically, but when connecting with user/password either something else has to have already triggered a start or you have to start it manually.  You can start it with "sqllocaldb start .\shareddb"

ORIGINAL: We have tried this and have had no luck.  The issue with LocalDb is that it based on the user account the process is running as.  We even tried running the app pool for the report server as the same account the database is running under, but could never get the designer to be able to connect to the database.