# Cannot connect from c# to sql locally but can remotely

Tags: c#, sql

I have  a c# application i want to connect it to sql server , the server and the application are used on the same machine , but I application cannot connect to the sql however if I installed the application on another machine and keeping the server in the first server they are connected !
The server is installed on windows 8.

Thanks

Comment: what is the connection string you are using?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3461900/65775) and the comments

Comment: @Mahmud<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=LENOVO;Initial Catalog=APP;User ID=sa;Password=111"/>

  </connectionStrings>



</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following -

1. Make sure your local database server has both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication mode enabled. But

If you are using Windows Authentication then change the connection string to -

```
connectionString="Data Source=LENOVO;Initial Catalog=APP;Integrated Security=True;"
```

If you are using SQL Server authentication mode, which it seems since you are providing username yourself then

```
connectionString="Data Source=LENOVO;Initial Catalog=APP;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=111"
```

Also, APP is usually a reserve keyword in some systems. Its better to avoid such name as the name of the DB.

If you are using default server instance you can use `.` or `(local)` instead of `LENOVO`

Comment: thanks a lot , there was coding error in my app and I solved it. thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Check that the firewall is not preventing you from connecting.