# Issue connecting to SQL database from .NET web app

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I have a .NET 4.0 web app with SQL 2008 R2 database sitting locally, all working fine.
I moved it on to a laptop (running IIS 7, installed .NET 4.5 framework, SQL 2008 Express, Management Studio Express, ) to show to the client.
I have the app pool configured to use the NT AUTHORITY / NETWORK SERVICE, and have given that access to the database.
When I run the app I get data in my drop-downs which are bound to simple SQL datasources so I am getting data, but when I run queries - searches, inserts etc I get the error below returned in the catch.
Ive done this set-up loads before but I cant think what Im missing or doing wrong this time. Don't know if it makes a difference but the original DB is R2, only 2008 installed on laptop. Anyone able to provide any hints?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (**provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Serve**r)

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express might help you

Comment: looks like exactly what I need - I did have the server name then \SQLEXPRESS but will follow the points further down the post, thanks