# How can I connect SQL Server 2014 in local when our server has installed sql 2012 and sql 2014 both?

Tags: sql-server

We have installed sql server 2012 and sql server 2014 express edition in my computer.

Now I am connecting sql server 2014 from another computer in network but that computer is connecting to the sql 2012 only not to the 2014.

I have open inbound rule for both port of sql servers. I have tried by stopping the service of sql 2012. However I can't connect to the sql 2014 from another computer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)

Comment: How are you trying to connect? The instance name of SQL Server Express is SQLEXPRESS. Use `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS` to connect to an Express instance on a machine, `.` or `MYSERVER` to connect to the default instance. Please don't start/stop services, you'll end up corrupting something.