# C++ [ODBC]-MSSQLExpress 2008 SQLSTATE: 28000 || 42000

Tags: c++, sql, windows, sql-server-2008, odbc

I'm facing some issues trying devloping a program that has to get informations from database and tables created under MSSQL 2008 management. 
I have to admit that I'm new to ODBC...
If anyone could help me with this issues? I tried two solutions to connect to my database [CodeA] and [CodeB]. I found documentation on google and tried a couple of solutions but until now can't find the right one.
Please have a look at my connection string below.

## CodeA:

```
SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle,NULL,
(SQLCHAR*)TEXT("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=TOWER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=tfe;UID=adminA;PWD=@Admin1;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;"),
SQL_NTS,retconstring,1024,NULL,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

## CodeB:

```
SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle,NULL,
(SQLCHAR*)TEXT("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=TOWER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=tfe.mdf;UID=adminA;PWD=@Admin1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"),
SQL_NTS,retconstring,1024,NULL,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

## CodeC:

```
SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle,NULL,
(SQLCHAR*)TEXT("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=TOWER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=tfe.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"),
SQL_NTS,retconstring,1024,NULL,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

The SQLSTATE that is returned from the execution.
[image: SQLSTATE]
While this are the roles attributed to my user:
[image: User roles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

I solved this problem by modifying the connection string to:

`"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=TOWER-PC;DATABASE=tfe;UID=adminA;PWD=@Admin1;"`

[Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25180369/3593740)