# SQL Server 2012 Management services does not appear

Tags: service, windows-8.1, ssms

I just installed SQL Server 2012 Management Studio x64 on Windows 8.i. I did a full installation including localDB, but when I check the services, it does not appear "SQL Server (SqlExpress)" neither "SQL Server Agent (SqlExpress)" or "SQL Server Browser".

What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: LocalDB does not create any services, LocalDB processes are started and stopped automatically when needed. Which download/installation file did you run?

Comment: Thanks, i can connect to remote server but and i can not connect to local database? I did a full installation includind localDB..

Comment: You are of course aware of the fact that it is possible to install only Management Studio without installing the actual Database Engine? This question, although describing SQL Server 2008, has a couple of things to check in the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express