# Access database over network

Tags: sql-server

I want to access my database over network. It gives error:

> Error: Cannot Connect to 192.168.0.2\SQLEXPRESS

I enabled the TCP/IP from SQL Configuration.

I turn off the firewall.

I allow SQL Server Authentication and Windows mode.

and I can ping to the ip-address.

Why I am not able to connect to database?

Comment: Have you tried connecting via SSMS? Is TCP/IP open for your SQL Server?

Comment: @gofr1 Yes it is Enabled.

Comment: Open a DOS prompt. What does `PING 192.168.0.1` return? If you log on locally can you connect? If you log on locally, you should confirm that that is the correct instance name (SQLEXPRESS)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it ping successfully, and on the server i am able to connect with 192.168.0.2\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect by specifying 192.168.0.2,1433 , here 1433 is port.

Comment: like 192.168.0.2, 1433\SQLEXPRESS ?

Comment: only 192.168.0.2,1433

Comment: If this is the case, you need to ensure the SQL Browser service is running on your server. Then you'll be able to connect by named instance. BTW SQLEXPRESS doesn't usually run on 1433 - are you sure you're connecting to the right instance?

Answer (score 1):

Probably is a server configuration problem. Try as follow.

On the server, open **SQL Server Configuration Manager**

Open *SQL Server Network Configuration* on the left panel and select *Protocols for YOURSERVERNAME*.

On the right panel double click on *TCP/IP* and be sure that *Enabled* is set to *Yes*.

Open the tab *IP Addresses* and set as *Yes* the *Active* and *Enabled* selection boxes where the IP Address is *192.168.0.2*.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a wrong instance name. If you want to connect to a default one  i.e. *MSSQLSERVER* use either dot (.) or a machine name or an IP address as a sever name.

If you are not sure what is the name of your instance just run *SQL Server Configuration Manager*. You can find it in Start menu. Then select *SQL Server Services* and there you should find something like *SQL Server (NAME_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE)*.

It is also worth reading this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143744%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express).