# How will I know the sql server database name to connect from SSMS

Tags: sql-server

Installed SSMS 2017 version. When I launch it first time, it asks for server name to connect to. I installed SQL server 2014 already. But I don't know the name of the server. I tried giving server name as "local". But it wouldn't accept. It says "Cannot connect to to local" Error: 53

Since I installed SQL server on my local machine, "local" should be acceptable name as a server to connect to from SSMS.

[server name?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQLv6.png)

Comment: Try `(local)` use the parenthesis around the word local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)

Answer (score 2):

.

localhost

127.0.0.1

Any of these will connect to sql server running on your local machine.

If you installed sql as a named instance, then .\myinstance, localhost\myinstance, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use (.), or local or localhost.

If you used named instance, follow the next:-

Use **Browse for more**, for getting the accurate server name as next screen shots;-

[image]

and under **Database Engine**, you will get the accurate server name

[image]

Comment: when I click on  "Server Name" and select "Browse", nothing shows up. And I don't see SQL Server Browser service at all on my machine.

Comment: it seems you installed SSMS, without installing SQL Serer Engine, Install SQL Server Engine 2017 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Answer (score 0):

If you have Db connection you can use this command

```
select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename
```

you can also check SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In Configuration Manager you need to find SQL Server Service. When you Double click the SQL Service and navigate through Service Tab, you need to see SQL Server Name

Comment: when I clicked on "SQL server configuration manager", it says "CAn't connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable"

Answer (score 0):

It should be localhost, just setup my SQL server last month and had to find this information aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You need connect using . only.

[image]

connect Local instance using .

[image]

[image]