# Connecting/Creating to a local Instance of Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL v17.9.1. I have used Microsoft SQL quite a bit for work, so know how to connect and query to external databases, but have never had to connect to a database on my own machine. At the moment I am trying to set up SQL on my own computer to connect to an SQL database on it but am having trouble finding the name of the local instance of SQL to type in.

Following the below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

I went to SQL Server Configuration Manager to make sure the correct process are running and SQL Server is running
[image]

I then went to my command prompt and typed in ipconfig to get my ipv4 and ipv6 to try in my SQL Server Management studio database engine server name and get the error message each time for both versions

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You hid the most important piece - What are you using as the instance name? SQL Express by default installs a named instance and not a default one, so you must specify it explicitly. Try server name - LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I was using my ipaddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't see what are you using to connect to that instance because it's hidden, but by the length of it you're either using your PC name or "SQLEXPRESS".

Either way, try this:

1) Start "SQL Server Browser"

2) Use localhost\SQLEXPRESS or hostname\SQLEXPRESS as Server Name in SSMS.

[How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)

Comment: Thanks I just needed the name localhost\SQLEXPRESS and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to your local machine using SSMS or using a computer to connect remotely to your server using SSMS ?

Have you specified a different port from default port on your SQL Server ?
- Connecting using just the IP address won't be enough without further configuration.. e.g 192.168.0.5\SQLEXPRESS (OK)